# Separation of variables ... $x,y \neq 0$assumption?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When separating variables in a differential equation, often we have to assume that the variables are not equal to $0$ so that division is possible. But what if $0$ is a solution?

I'm currently looking at this problem which involves division by both $x$ and $y$: $$xy' = y + xy$$

So. $y = 0$ seems like a solution. Is $x = 0$ also a solution? It ends up being $0 = y$ which I am not sure what means?

Comment: what do you mean by x=0 a solution? I assume y is a function of x. eg y(x).

Comment: Well, that's what I am confused about. What does it mean exactly that $x = 0$? Obviously a solution is a function of $x$, but in order to find these solutions, I divided by $x$. What would it mean if $x = 0$ was true?

Comment: If the function $y(x)=0$ is a solution, you cannot have any $\frac1y$-terms. So we have to treat that as a separate case, by checking if it satisfies the original equation. Then you use separation of variables to check for any _other_ solutions. As for $x=0$, remember that $y$ is really $y(x)$, so the $x=0$ case really states that $0\cdot y'(0)=y(0)$, which means that either $y(0)=0$, or $y'$ goes to infinity as $x\to0$

Answer (score 0):

$x\,dy/dx = y + xy$

$1/y\, dy=  dx\,(1+x)/x$

$\ln(y) = x+\ln(x)$

$y = e^x x \cdot C_1$

Division by x should not matter. I think the reason is, because you are going to integrate by dx anyway, so the discontinuity which is just a zeroset vanishes...